# How can I view the number of files in each folder in Ubuntu one folder?

Tags: ubuntu-one, nautilus, directory

I think, it would be nice, to see the number of files in each folder, to know if the synchronization of Ubuntu one is finished or not.

Answer (score 2):

Change the folder view like so:
[image: folder view]

Comment: No, only see the number of archives, and the total sice of the folder.

Comment: The size shows the number of files in each folder.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm asking about Ubuntu One files. I want to know, how many files are sincronized in U1, and the size of each file and folder

Answer (score 0):

In the menu you find view.
And there the 5th menu = "Statusleiste" ( german) status bar ?

Then you see the number of objects at the bottom of the window

Comment: Sorry, but I'm asking about Ubuntu One files. I want to know, how many files are sincronized in U1, and the size of each file and folder